# Careers site links me to deleted Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I had an unused Google OpenID Stack Overflow account, which I wanted to link with the account I was using (Facebook login). I couldn't do it, so I deleted it, and linked it later.

But now [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) still shows the deleted account as my Stack Overflow account with 1 reputation (instead of the reputation on the real one). I cannot convince it to start showing the account I actually own.

Is there a way I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-synced your Careers <-> SO link. It looks like it's now showing your correct account. I.E. the system had rodents and I smacked them with a hammer.

Comment: Never underestimate rodents.

Comment: Never underestimate hammers.